# NTFS format /dev/sda2 not working with gparted

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted

I am trying to format my partition into Ntfs format, so I can go back to Windows10.

In order to do so, I downloaded and tried to use gparted, but it is not working.

I have tried to format it directly, but it failed since either
1. It's locked or
2. There is no ntfs optiopn

I have already installed ntfsprogs in my machine.

Is there any suggestion for me? 
[image]

p.s. I have tired to partition the /dev/sda2 drive, but that has not worked either.It seems because it's locked or so? When I right click the drive, option of "Resize/Move" and "Format to" are all disabled.

p.s. I tried to format the drive using "Disk Utility" but it gave me a message   Error unmounting /dev/sda2: Command-line `umount  "/dev/sda2"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: umount: /: target is busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD and run **gparted** or **Disk Utility** from there.

See the "key" icons next to the **/dev/sdaN** name? That means that the partition is mounted, and you won't be able to do anything with that partition until you unmount it first. You can unmount it in **gparted**.

Of course, *we don't really want you to wipe Ubuntu and go back to Windows*. Is there a reason to do so? Better to resize the Ubuntu partition to the right, and reinstall Windows to the left, and then you can dual-boot to either Windows or Ubuntu.

**Update #1:**

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- download the desired .iso file from http://releases.ubuntu.com/
- burn the .iso file to DVD/USB
- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **resize** /dev/sda2 by moving the left side of the partition to the right
- click the Apply button
- install Windows into the new unallocated space

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is your second option viable without running Ubuntu ISO burned image on my USB drive? That sounds tedious. If there is a way to partition my /dev/sda2 INTO 2 different ones without burned iso image, can you teach me about the method?

Comment: @trentacoollime see the update to my answer. Please remember to accept my answer if it's helpful, and solves your problem. Thanks!